# Is there any Python/numpy equivalent to Matlab's [row,col] = find(X)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have this code in Matlab

```
[r,c] = find (X)
```

According to Matlab's doc, this  ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶i̶c̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶s̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶n̶o̶n̶z̶e̶r̶o̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶p̶u̶t̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶m̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶p̶e̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶l̶y̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶`̶r̶`̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶`̶c̶ returns the row and column subscripts of each nonzero element in array X

I need to do the same in Python and I've found that `numpy np.nonzero(X)` does something similar but it only returns the values in `c`.

How do I get also the values in `r`?

Some code I tried:

```
x = np.array([1,0,3,0,5])
```

If I do `r,c = np.nonzero(x)`

I get `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

I want to `obtain r = [0,0,0]` and `c = [0,2,4]`

Comment: How about `np.where` and `np.nonzero`?

Comment: argwhere is giving you [r,c] pairs (i.e., it's the same data as from Matlab, but reshaped).  It's the transpose of np.nonzero which @Divakar mentioned.  Pick whichever shape is most convenient for further processing.

Comment: @Divakar I saw [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49600202#49600202) yesterday and I immediately thought about you

Comment: Let's say I have in python xy = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]). If I do np.nonzero(xy) I get the index of each element of xy which is not zero. Which is my r. If then I do np.argwhere(xy>2) I expect to get the values which satisfy the condition (being > 2) i.e. 3,4,5 but I get again the index of this values, not the values themselves which I need. Which is my c

Comment: If you need values too, simply index : `X[r,c]`.

Comment: what do you mean by  X[r,c]? Is that Python code? Sorry I don't understand

Comment: Yes, `r,c = np.nonzero(X); values = X[r,c]`.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong about what the find function does. I edited the original post. Now I just need a function that returns row and column of each non zero value in my array

Comment: further testing shows that I was getting errors because x is a 1d array, while modifying it to be a 2d array x = np.array([[1,0,3,0,5]] makes possible to use r,c = np.nonzero(x). This way I get both r and c as inquired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the issue by myself.

Doing `rc = np.nonzero(x)` gives only row values because of the way `x` is declared.

That way `x` is a 1d array. If `x` is declared instead as a 2d array like

```
x = np.array([[1,0,3,0,5]])
```

then `rc` is going to store both row and columns indexes of each element respecting the condition (being non zero in this case)